# How are function calls resolved?

Tags: c, function, linker

When a function is called, execution is shifted to a point indicated by the function pointer. At the start of execution, the executable code has to be loaded from disk.

How is the correct function pointer called? The executable code is not mapped into virtual memory at the same location every time, right? So how does the runtime make sure that a call to a function always calls the correct function even if the location of the executable code is different for each execution?

Consider the following code:

```
void func(void); //Func defined in another dynamic library

int main()
{
    func();
    //How is the pointer to func known if the file containing func is loaded from disk at run time?
};
```

Comment: What is the programming problem you're having? Or are you simply curious about how computers work? (StackOverflow is for solving programming problems.) If you're just curious, you can read about relocation.

Comment: This is done by the [loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing))

Comment: @RaymondChen I am simply curious about what happens during the loading process.

Comment: In this particular case, the [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)

Comment: Every address (function or global/static variable) is relative to the base-address of the process (the starting address of the memory block into which the executable is loaded). So every address in your program is essentially an offset. The translation of that offset in the CPU is done by adding the base-address of the process to that offset, thus obtaining the physical address. The HW component "in charge" of that is called MMU (memory-management unit). All of this has nothing to do with C of course (the C-language standard is "oblivious" to those details).

Comment: @barakmanos Is this also true for dynamic linking ? How can you offset something you haven't compiled nor linked yet ?

Comment: @clement_frndz: No, I was referring to address resolving of statically-linked functions. DLL functions are resolved differently on each OS. On Windows, for example, it goes through the registry, looking up the function by its literal name (I believe).

Comment: There is not registry involved. The PE file defines which library it imports (by name) and for each imported library, which symbols it imports (the symbol is roughly the name of the function or global variable). Do a `objdump -p foo.exe' and you'll see lists of imported DLLs and for each one the imported symbols.

Comment: if you are dealing with libraries, then you are dealing with a particular operating system, so your answers aren't going to be portable, and if it is a static library then it isn't external and isn't a function pointer at all... it is just internal..

Comment: in general, the 'runtime' has nothing to do with the location of the function in the user memory space.  Rather, the link step (comes right after the compile step) handles all of the finding, locating, etc.   If using 'static' libraries, that is all there is to it.  If using dynamic libraries, then the 'load' step (about the second step after the user requests the program to run) loads the appropriate portions of the libraries, and finishes fillling in the start addresses for those library functions.   It is possible to load a library function at run time, via the source code, but why bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that function pointers are resolved is really quite simple. When the compiler chain spits out an executable binary, all internal addresses are relative to a "base address." In some executable formats, this base address is specified, in others it is implied.

Basically, the compiler says that it assumes execution will start at address A. The runtime decides that it should actually start at B. The runtime then subtracts A and adds B to all non-relative addresses in the binary before executing it.

This process also applies to things like DLLs. Dynamic libraries store a list of addresses relative to the base pointer that point to each exported function. Names are often also associated with the list, so that you can reference a function by name. When the library is loaded, the address translation is applied to everything, including the address table. At that point, a caller just has to look up the address in the table that was translated, and then they'll have the absolute address of a given function.

In older operating systems, long long ago (and, in some cases, even today), well before things like address space layout randomization, memory pages, and multitasking operating systems, programs would just be copied to the specified base address in memory where it would then be executed.

In modern operating systems, one of a few things can happen, depending on the capabilities or requirements of the platform and application. Most operating systems handle native binaries as I described in the second paragraph, however some applications (such as running 16-bit x86 on later architectures) can involve more complex strategies. One such strategy involves giving the code a static virtual address space. This has various limitations, such as the need for an emulation/compatibility layer if you want it to interact with external code (like a windowed console or the network stack).

As the need for 16-bit support declines though, that sort of scheme is used less and less. Giving all programs their own unique address space (rather than letting it overlap) promotes the use of shared libraries, services, and other shared goodies.

Answer (score 0):

In general, function calls are resolved statically. When you compile the file, first - .o (or .obj) file is created. All known addresses - are local functions (from this file). Unknown are "extern" functions.
Then, linking is performed. Linking completes address mapping for every function which is "extern". If any names are missing - linking error occurs.

> How is the correct function pointer called?
>   Function pointer is function address, function name is function address. Both are values, not L-values. &func and func are absolutely same.

Loading or PE (or ELF) files is a process or loading the executable to memory. Too much information to explain. Basically, just for clarification, consider: every function has its own address in the process address space.

Answer (score -1):

You can print the 'func' and see whether is has the same address during every execution like this:

```
printf("%u", function);
```

For me it's the same address every time (virtual memory wise).